# getting the current class object

Tags: java

I have three classes.. A,B,C.

1. In both classes B and C i have a static string variable "name" which contains the name of B and C, as-

> ```
>  class B
>      {
>      static name;
>      public static void main(String args[])
>      {
>      name="Class B";
>      A.getName();
>      }
> ```

1. I am calling class A's getName method from class B and C.. Class A is as follows:

> class A
>      {
>
> ```
> getName()
> {
> System.out.println(this class called me);
> }
> }
> ```

class C is:

> ```
>  class C
>      {
>      static name;
>      public static void main(String args[])
>      {
>      name="Class C";
>      A.getName();
>      }
> ```

Now my question is, what code should i use in place of "this class called me" in class A so that i get the name of whichever class calls A! I hope i am clear!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A {
    getName()
    {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        int lastStackElement = stackTraceElements.length-1;
        String callingObjectsName = stackTraceElements[lastStackElement].getClassName();
        System.out.println(callingObjectsName + " called me.");
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to access the classthatcalledme's name variable.. that's all .. i don't want any stack trace!!

Comment: @user975234  Give the update a shot.  To get access to the classes name you need to inspect the stack trace.

Comment: @Shawn I just provide the weapons, what damage they do with them is their own business. J/K

Comment: that works! and that's cool.. but can u please explain what damage it does! :P

Comment: I think OP wants element 1, not element length-1, no?

Comment: @user975234 Its not so much that the code does damage, its how you got into the position in the first place of needing to find the calling classes name.  Respectfully, this is what is know as a code "smell", because something smells funny, the problem you are facing could most likely be handled using a better design.  I believe this is what TJ was alluding to.

Comment: @yshavit you need to subtract 1 because arrays are zero indexed while .length() returns the number of elements in the array.  If an array has a length of 7, the last element in the array is in index 6.

Comment: actually.. i was trying to make a chat application. I made a separate class for GUI and was then calling the GUI separately in client and server classes. Now i wanted the name of the person who's sending the chat. So i set the name individually in server and client so that i could use that name in the GUI class to set the current sender's name! May be a bit messed up!

Comment: So you are switching based upon who called the class to go find the name?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Right, except the last element of the array contains the oldest frame (e.g., main() or the thread's run()), whereas the OP wants the second to newest frame -- the newest (element 0) being the current frame, from which getStackTrace() was invoked.

Comment: @user975234 Why don't you just have the sender's name be an argument to the method?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: but still .. i am not able to print the name according to the variable .. it's printing the class name .. i need to print the value in the variable "name"!

Comment: @user975234 I just added another answer, which suggests another way to do what you're getting at -- but also gives (in prose, not code) the steps you need to get the variable "name"

Answer (score 2):

Your `A.getName` method cannot know what class's code called it. You have to pass that information into it.

Okay, so that's *not strictly true*, you could figure it out by generating a stack trace and inspecting that. But it would be a very bad idea. In general, if a method needs to know something, you either A) Make it part of an instance that has that information as instance data, or B) Pass the information into it as an argument.

Comment: so it means there's nothing like, thisclasscalledme.name ? name is defined both in class B and class C

Comment: i want to access the classthatcalledme's name variable.. that's all

Comment: @user975234 do you know what `static` is?

Answer (score 0):

```
Modify your code to something like this:

class A 
{
   getName(String className) 
   {
      System.out.println(className);
   }
}

and use it like :

 class B
 {
     static name;
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
       name="Class B";
       A.getName(name);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're really trying to do is to pass information from one stack frame to another one -- and specifically, from a frame A to a frame B, where A invoked B. This is an easy thing to do, and I think you're over-engineering it.

```
public class B {
    static String name = ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.getName(name);
    }
}
public class C {
    static String name = ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.getName(name);
    }
}

public class A {
    public static void getName(String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Your approach would require:

1. Getting the stack trace
2. Using that to get the calling stack frame, which is element 1 in the stack trace array
3. Using that to get the class name for the calling method
4. Using `Class.forName` to get the `Class<?>` object
5. Calling `getField("name")` on that `Class<?>` object to get a `Field` object
6. (optional but recommended) Confirming that the `Field` represents static field of type String
7. calling `get(null)` on the `Field` to get its value (the `null` represents the object for which you want the field -- since the field is static and thus not tied to any object, this argument is ignored), and casting this value down to `String`

Or, instead you could:

1. Just pass the name to the function that needs it.

Your approach also requires that the `name` field be static, since there's no way to get the calling *instance* (even though you can get the calling instance's class). The simpler approach works even if `name` is an instance field.